# How to use HibernateItemWriter with spring Batch 2 and Hibernate 4?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch

When using hibernate 3, the following code works:

```
<bean id="ivsHibernateWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" id="hibernateTemplate" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

After upgrading to hibernate 4, my test failes with this exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder
```

I thought of changing the hibernateTemplate bean to be inline with hibernate 4, like so:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate" id="hibernateTemplate" >
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

However, this class does not exist.

How should we work with Hibernate4 and spring Batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for now, since Spring Batch does not support hibernate4 .
You may see the Jira issue about this https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1904

I kindly suggest working with JdbcItemWriters in case you do not have a strict business requirement; imho, hibernate and jpa are poorly supported in spring batch (and I understand why).

Comment: Hibernate 4 is supported since Spring Batch release 2.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think Spring Batch support for Hibernate 4 is already there. No need to inject `hibernateTemplate` inside `HibernateItemWriter`. Only `sessionFactory` injection is sufficient. For more details, check out [this link](http://www.javatopper.blogspot.in/2014/12/springing-into-batch-job.html)